# logstash running lumberjack, indexer stops unexpected after a few minutes

Tags: logstash

I am trying to setup some log stash shipper and one logstash indexer on a few different machines. Everything works fine except that indexer will just stop after a few minutes without any warning or errors. It just stop.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting up the indexer to send debug data to STDOUT

```
output {
   stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
}
```

And then look at the Logstash log file

Are you sure its the Indexer that is stopping?

Normally, the problem is with either Redis or Elasticsearch.

The Indexer is just a JVM process that pulls data out of Redis and sends it to Elasticsearch.

The logstash logfile will tell you what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, the stdout helped, because I am using lumberjack, so I don't go through redis at all.